# How to use ReactiveCommand canexecute

Tags: command, prism, reactiveui

I'm new in WPF, implementing application using reactiveUI.
I have one button and added command handler for it.
want to call the method only when canExecute is true.

in viewmodel, i have defined it

```
public bool canExecute 
{
  get { return _canExecute;}
  set { _canExecute = value;}
}

Bind()
{
 AddRecord = new ReactiveCommand(_canExecute);

    AddRecord .Subscribe(x => 
    {
       AddR()
}
}
void AddR()
{
}
```

but its not working. how to convert it in to System.IObservable?

Comment: I don't know if you are using an older version of ReactiveUI, but the current version takes in an IObservable<bool> as a constructor parameter.  Looks like you are passing in a bool, which I don't know but from just what you have, would be false anyway and not support changes.  At a minimum you might want: new ReactiveCommand(this.WhenAnyValue(t => t.canExecute).Select(b => b==true))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @jomtois mentions, you need to fix your declaration of CanExecute:

```
bool canExecute;
public bool CanExecute {
    get { return canExecute; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref canExecute, value); }
}
```

Then, you can write:

```
AddRecord = new ReactiveCommand(this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.CanExecute));
```

Why go to all this effort? This makes it so that when CanExecute changes, ReactiveCommand automatically enables / disables. However, this design is pretty imperative, I wouldn't create a CanExecute boolean, I'd think about how I can combine properties related to my ViewModel that have a semantic meaning.

Comment: can you elaborate more on combining properties related to viewmodel.

Comment: getting error missing a using directive or assembly reference. which assembly do i need to reference.?

Comment: I can't elaborate more without you explaining the domain of your problem more

Comment: Can you please update your answer, looks like it is no longer valid as `ReactiveCommand` has been made static.